# Simple Android Program Uploading to the Internet

Tags: java, android

Mine is a simple Android program uploading a file containing some text data to a certain server on the Internet. I wish to display a "circular" busy icon as the application uploads.

Do I need to hard code animation in Java or in XML layout? How would I make my Service component, which is busy uploading,  communicate with the component that is showing the "circular" busy so that the circular ring disappears? Thanks.

--- softwarelover

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of examples of AsynchTask class which has a postExecute method to allow you to stop the spinner

Answer (score 0):

You need to just write an asynck task as given below

```
AsyncTask<Void,Vois,Void> myAsyncTask;

myAsyncTask=new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
progrssDialog= new ProgressDialog(DeleteAppActivity.this);
progrssDialog.setCancelable(false);
progrssDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
progrssDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progrssDialog.show();

}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
response ="no response";
response=ServerUtilities.uploadFileOnserver();
return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {         
super.onPostExecute(result);
progrssDialog.dismiss();
    //perform action according to response

        if(respose.equals("success")){
          //show success message

        }else if(response.equals("failure"))

          //show error message
        }else {

         //show connectivity error message
        }
     }
   };

  myAsyncTask.execute(null,null,null);
```